# Difference between i-vector and d-vector

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, deep-learning

could someone please explain the difference between i-vector and d-vector? All I know about them is that they are widely used in speaker/speech recognition systems and they are kind of templates for representing speaker information, but I don't know the main differences.

Answer (score 16):

I-vector is a feature that represents the idiosyncratic characteristics of the frame-level features' distributive pattern. I-vector extraction is essentially a dimensionality reduction of the GMM supervector (although the GMM supervector is not extracted when computing the i-vector). It's extracted in a similar manner with the eigenvoice adaptation scheme or the JFA technique, but is extracted per sentence (or input speech sample).

On the other hand, d-vector is extracted using DNN. To extract a d-vector, a DNN model that takes stacked filterbank features (similar to the DNN acoustic model used in ASR) and generates the one-hot speaker label (or the speaker probability) on the output is trained. D-vector is the averaged activation from the last hidden layer of this DNN. So unlike the i-vector framework, this doesn't have any assumptions about the feature's distribution (the i-vector framework assumes that the i-vector, or the latent variable has a Gaussian distribution).

So in conclusion, these are two distinct features extracted from totally different methods or assumptions. I recommend you reading these papers:

N. Dehak, P. Kenny, R. Dehak, P. Dumouchel, and P. Ouellet, "Front-end factor analysis for speaker verification," *IEEE Transactions on Audio, Speech, and Language Processing*, vol. 19, no. 4, pp. 788-798, 2011.

E. Variani, X. Lei, E. McDermott, I. L. Moreno, and J. G-Dominguez, "Deep neural networks for small footprint text-dependent  speaker verification," in *Proc. ICASSP*, 2014, pp. 4080-4084.

Comment: What is `frame-level` ?

Comment: By "frame-level features", I meant the acoustic features (e.g., MFCC) extracted from each speech frame.

Comment: What is `speech frame`?

Comment: "Speech frame" is essentially a small segment from the speech. For example, you can extract an acoustic feature every 10 ms (this is usually called a frame step or stride) with a context window of 25 ms. In this case, these 25 ms speech segments are the frames, and thus the acoustic features extracted from each frame are called frame-level features. You should check out this link to get the gist of it: http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to properly characterize the d-vector in plain language, but I can help a little.

The identity vector, or **i-vector**, Is a spectral signature for a particular slice of speech, usually a sliver of a phoneme, rarely (as far as I can see) as large as the entire phoneme.  Basically, it's a discrete spectrogram expressed in a form isomorphic to the Gaussian mixture of the time slice.

**EDIT**

*Thanks to those who provided comments and a superior answer.  I updated this only to replace the incorrect information from my original attempt.*

A **d-vector** is extracted from a Deep NN, the mean of the feature vectors in the DNN's final hidden layer.  This becomes the model for the speaker, used to compare against other speech samples for identification.

Comment: I absolutely disagree with the statement that d-vector is extracted from a sequence of i-vectors. d-vector is extracted from (D)NN model and i-vector from GMM model.

Comment: I agree, the i-vector explanation is quite good, but the d-vector is explanation is wrong, per E. Variani, X. Lei, E. McDermott, I. L. Moreno, and J. G-Dominguez, "Deep neural networks for small footprint text-dependent speaker verification," in Proc. ICASSP, 2014, pp. 4080-4084.